# Delete data from child table(relational) in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am having problem while deleting list of rows from child table which primary key is associated with many child table's rows.

```
public async Task<bool> Handle(SaveProcessingGroupCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if(request.processingGroupDto.ProcessingGroupID > 0)
    {
        var processingGroupDb = await processingGroupRepository.GetProcessingGroupAndDetails(request.processingGroupDto.ProcessingGroupID);
        //var processingGroup = mapper.Map<ProcessingGroupDto>(processingGroupDb);

        if (processingGroupDb is not null) /// Update
        {
            var processingGroup = mapper.Map<ProcessingGroupDto>(processingGroupDb);
            if (processingGroup.ProcessingGroupDetailsNavigation.Count > 0) /// Delete details if not exist in the request
            {
                var processingGroupDetailIDs = processingGroup.ProcessingGroupDetailsNavigation.Select(x => x.ProcessingGroupDetailID).ToArray();

                var requestProcessingGroupDetailIDs = request.processingGroupDto.ProcessingGroupDetailsNavigation.Select(x => x.ProcessingGroupDetailID).ToArray();

                var exceptIds = processingGroupDetailIDs.Except(requestProcessingGroupDetailIDs).ToList();
                if (exceptIds.Count > 0)
                {
                    var deleteProcessingGroupDetailList = processingGroup.ProcessingGroupDetailsNavigation.Where(x => exceptIds.Contains(x.ProcessingGroupDetailID)).ToList();
                    var processingGroupDetailsList = mapper.Map<List<ProcessingGroupDetail>>(deleteProcessingGroupDetailList);
                    await processingGroupDetailRepository.DeleteItemsAsync(processingGroupDetailsList);
                }                        
            }
            var result = mapper.Map(request.processingGroupDto, processingGroupDb);
            await processingGroupRepository.UpdateAsync(result);
        }  
    }
    else /// Add
    {
        var processingGroup = mapper.Map<ProcessingGroup>(request.processingGroupDto);
        processingGroup.DynamicYN = false;
        await processingGroupRepository.InsertAsync(processingGroup);
    }
    return await processingGroupRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveDataAsync();
}
```

I tried to convert the the object into dto and then just get the list of deletedItems and delete them

Comment: There's no EF Core code in the question. Only a lot of mappings and what seems like the "repository" antipattern. EF Core neither has nor needs single-entity CRUD classes. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. All changes to all tracked projects are detected and persisted in a single database transaction when `SaveChanges` is called, effectively "committing" the Unit of Work. There's no `SaveChanges` in this code.

Comment: EF Core deals with objects, not rows. If you want to delete an object, call `DbContext.Remove(thatObject);` or `RemoveRange(manyObjects)` for a list of objects. When `SaveChanges` is called all objects marked for deletion will be deleted. If cascade deletion is configured in `OnModelConfiguring`, child entities will be deleted as well